# JQuery update causes unrecognized expression error

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update my jQuery version from 1.10.2 to 3.6.0. When I use the 3.6.0 version, I get the following error - "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href$=]" This does not occur with version 1.10.2.

Here is the script where the error occurs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var anchor_hash = location.hash;
var anchor_link = $("a[href$=" + anchor_hash + "]").closest(".gb-div");
var expand_image = $("a[href$=" + anchor_hash + "]").closest(".gb-div").prevAll("li:first");
var close_icon = '<img src="image/gb-close-icon.svg" class="image-expand">';    
var anchor_list = $("a[href$=" + anchor_hash + "]").parent();
var original_color = $(anchor_list).css('background-color');
var time = 3500;
anchor_link.slideDown(0); 
expand_image.children('.gb-expand').children(".gb-expand-icon").html(close_icon);
```

All of my other jQuery script works fine with version 3.6.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have # character in achor_hash? if yes, please replace # with "#"

Comment: Side note: It is more efficient to store a reference to an element than querying the DOM for it multiple times in the same code block. `var $a = $(selector), $gb = $a.closest('.gb-div'), $list = $gb.parent() etc....`

Answer (score 3):

Location.hash will include #. I would recommend simply wrapping the value in single quotes.

```js
anchor_hash = "#test"
var anchor_link = $("a[href$='" + anchor_hash + "']");

//returns 1
console.log(anchor_link.length);

//causes an error
 var anchor_link = $("a[href$=" + anchor_hash + "]");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#test">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. Adding the single quotes to the selector and the following "if" condition to the script fixed it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var anchor_hash = location.hash;
if (anchor_hash.length != "") {
var anchor_link = $("a[href$='" + anchor_hash + "']").closest(".gb-div");
```

Answer (score -1):

As i see you getting error caus of empty `location.hash` and broken selectors on line 3 and 4. Try to add check `location.hash` value isn't empty.